# How many innocents died on the second Death Star when the rebels destroyed it?

Tags: star-wars, death-star, return-of-the-jedi

When the Rebels destroyed the second Death Star at the end of *Return of The Jedi* how many innocents died as well, since the station was still under construction?

Did the Empire move construction crews away for the battle, or were they still on board? I’ve seen people state that millions of slaves were involved in Death Stars construction?

Comment: no innocents were harmed. a roofer's personal politics come heavily into play when choosing jobs, and a roofer listens to his heart, not his wallet.

Comment: There's some info on its complement at http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Star_II, but it doesn't clarify how many were actually there and there's a vague reference to "many personnel evacuating" that is only sourced to the movie.

Comment: @phantom42 are slaves not innocent?

Comment: @phantom42 I think you forgot your sarcasm tag.

Comment: @phantom42, I guess we are too old ^^

Comment: i forgot my clerks tag

Comment: related, not dupe: [Did the Empire use independent contractors to build either of the Death Stars?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/64537/5184)

Comment: @Himarm - Is there canon evidence the Empire used slaves in the construction of the Death Star? With slaves there is some danger of sabotage, I think it would make more sense if they used some combination of loyalists and droids.

Comment: @hypnosifi - under the LucasCanon, Wookies were known to have been slaves working on the death star. I *think* it references it in the DisneyCanon novel *Tarkin*, but I'm not sure

Comment: @SSumner *Tarkin* mentions slave labor, but does not say that they were Wookiees.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Yes, [slaves were used in the construction of the first Death Star](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/108062/31936) (and probably the second as well).

Comment: Related, Not dupp. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36238/what-is-the-total-number-of-people-killed-on-the-2-death-stars-when-they-explode

Comment: @phantom42 Where is the roof on a Death Star?

Comment: Related, not dupe:  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108066/did-the-rebels-know-how-many-people-were-on-the-death-star

Comment: @Hypnosifl Trying hard to avoid Godwin's Law, but a certain real-world faction to which the Galactic Empire bears some resemblance actually used slave labor for weapons building. If they "trusted" their slaves, why wouldn't the Empire? Of course, this faction (fortunately) didn't have access to droids, which would have solved many of their problems; on the other hand, they had the policy of "extermination through hard labor".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like the death toll of workers on the 2nd death star could be fairly low. Quoting part of [TenthJustice's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/64544/29220).

Wookieepedia describes the second Death Star as being primarily constructed by droids:

> Methods of faster construction had been developed in the years since
>   the original station's conception, added to the fact that Imperial
>   engineers made sure to allocate enough space on the station for the
>   maximum possible amount of self-replicating construction droids.

Their source for that claim is an official book called *Star Wars: Complete Locations*.

On top of that, according to George Lucas, the first star destroyer was at least built with

> ...I came up with the idea of adding a little schematic of the Death Star in here, because the Geonosians build robots and build things, they're sort of construction workers. They would probably be the ones contracted to build the Death Star, and they were the ones that Jay and Silent Bob worry got killed on the Death Star, but they are after all a bunch of large termites.

We are not to feel bad for the workers because they are essentially insects that breed in mass quantities. Obi-Won and Anakin also kill them fairly freely in the movies compared to them killing other life forms.

Comment: FWIW, the Bounty Hunter book established that the second Death Star's droids were almost entirely under the control of one of the IG-88 assassin droids (one of the others seen as a bounty hunter in the fifth film).

Answer (score 0):

The Death Star II is no longer under construction when the battle begins. When the Emperor showed up, Darth Vader reports, "The Death Star will be completed on schedule." Later, the Emperor reveals to Luke that the station is fully armed and operational. So it's done. Sure, they could put some paint on the walls, and maybe hang a few pictures, but it's done. It doesn't have to look pretty.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they would have finished the exposed structure once the Rebels were destroyed.

Comment: @user339676 Why? It does everything it is supposed to do. Do you really think The Empire cares about the aesthetics of the thing?

Comment: That seems to be the **only** thing they care about.  Certainly their security and weapons had little functional value in practice - white armor that gives no protection, security that is always penetrated, ships built far from any settlement...

Comment: Plus, the Death Star still has some pretty gaping holes in it. They only got it operational before it was structurally completed because the Emperor knew the Rebels were coming. Also, I doubt the Emperor would half-ass something like the Death Star.

Comment: @user339676 Can you imagine what that thing cost? At this point all that is necessary is the minimum viable product, especially after the Rebels are gone. They're done.

Comment: I don't buy it. Is there any indication in Canon/Legends that they *weren't* planning on finishing it? The Death Star wasn't just about defeating the Rebels. As Moff Tarkin put it in ANH, "Fear will keep the local systems in line!" Its purpose was to allow to Empire to rule with an iron fist. When Death Star I was destroyed, it was a huge enabler for the Alliance. That, and losing all representation in the Imperial Senate drove everyone over the edge. Rebellion was everywhere. They *needed* another Death Star. I assume by that, they weren't just gonna half finish the thing and call it a day.

Answer (score -1):

Zero.  Even if any construction workers are on board, they knew they were working on a government super weapon, and that would likely put them at risk.  They would not really be innocent, but would be material accessories to mass murder and some pretty significant environmental crimes.

In the real world, such projects like this come with stringent requirements on the workers, and the workers usually command a higher salary commensurate with the added risk involved.

Comment: The original death star supposedly was built woth slave labor, if slaves are involved then it different the hired workers

Comment: @Himarm, This question specifically mentions the Second Death Star.  There is no evidence in the movie that slave labor was used to construct it.  The few scenes about this issue suggest that they are imperial workers.

Answer (score -4):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and state that not even the slaves are innocent.  All of them chose to help put weapons of enormous destructive potential into the hands of an utterly ruthless dictatorship.  Mass murder and tyranny were the obvious objectives of the Death Star's construction.  Without their obedience, the tyrant's capacity to murder and/or terrorize the populace is hindered, if not made impossible outright.

Remember that without obedience, tyranny becomes *impossible*.

So each and every one of the slaves who obeyed orders to build this thing chose to value one life (their own) or a small handful of lives (their own and their family's) over the lives of many millions of other people.

Not innocent.  None of them.  Not even one.

Comment: I don’t think this really answers the question. While the “technical” wording of the question may require people to make a moral judgement of “innocence,” it seems pretty clear that the question is really about the death toll of civilian workers, regardless of moral culpability.